# This null pointer is really annoying me-please help!

Tags: java, wicket

Can anyone help me with the following null pointer exception issue please:

```
AjaxButton viewResult = new AjaxButton("test"){
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target,Form form){
        try {
            retrieveTestID();
            System.out.println(testID);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        results=new ArrayList();
        DB db=new DB();
        try{
            db.connect();
            String query = 
              "Select Stud_Username,result from students2tests where Test_ID=" 
              + testID;

            System.out.println(query);
            ResultSet rs=db.execSQL(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                Result result = new Result( rs.getString("Stud_Username"), 
                                            rs.getInt("result"));
                results.add(result);
            }
            if(results.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("I'm empty, there is error");
            }
            else{
                //this is being printed so results isnt empty
                System.out.println("NOT EMPTY");
            }
            db.close();
            /***seems to be throwing an error because of this line***/
            ResultsTable table=new ResultsTable(results);
            setResponsePage(table);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ReesultsTable class(a dataview)

```
public class ResultsTable extends BasePage {
    private ArrayList resultsList;

    public ResultsTable(ArrayList res){
        res=resultsList;
        if(resultsList.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("I am empty,beware");
        }else{
            System.out.println("I am not emty-no worries!!!");  
        }

        final DataView dataView = new DataView("studresult", 
            new ListDataProvider(resultsList)) {
                public void populateItem(final Item item) {
                    final Result studres = (Result) item.getModelObject();
                    item.add(new Label("username", studres.getUsername()));
                    item.add(new Label("result", "" + studres.getResult()));
                }
            };

        dataView.setItemsPerPage(10);
        add(dataView);
        add(new PagingNavigator("navigator", dataView));
    }
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: What line does the exception occur on and can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your ResultsTable constructor, you are always saving the member variable resultsList (initialized to null) to the res ArrayList parameter. Swap the sides of the first line, and it might be OK. In other words, you want the first line of the constructor to be

```
resultsList = res;
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-) @E Shindler: Next time, please post the stack trace. It makes remote diagnosis **much** easier.

Comment: but of course!!! Thank you-I hate silly things like that!